# Unspecified data type data parsing in Java

Tags: java, android, json

How would you parse the below string response data in Java?

```
anyType{
    resultCode=405000000; 
    resultDesc=Operation successful.; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String.split('{') 
would get you two String

> "anytype"

and

> "resultCode=405000000; 
>       resultDesc=Operation successful.;  }"

For the second String You can Use

```
 String.split(";",2) //For 2 results
```

The remaining "}" will be filtered